# Common scale for pgfplots groupplot

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

The `groupplots` environment allows global values of `xmax` to be set.  Is there a way to automatically select a common value for all plots in a group?  For example, with the code below, the 4th plot does not have the same x-scale as the other 3 plots.  Is it possible to have all 4 plots use the same x-axis without manually defining a maximum x value (in this case, '2')?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2}]
\nextgroupplot
\addplot coordinates{(0,0)(1,1)(2,2)};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot coordinates{(0,2)(1,1)(2,0)};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot coordinates{(0,2)(1,1)(2,1)};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot coordinates{(0,2)(1,1)(1,0)};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can achieve the same scale via `axis equal=true`, but that might not be exactly what you want as the last graph does not have the same `xmin`, `xmax`, but not sure if that is required.

Comment: That does provide the correct scale, but I was ultimately looking to use `x descriptions at=edge bottom`, which, with the example provided, provides the wrong axis labels for the second plot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `every plot/.style` key to enter the common settings in that group

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2,
                               every plot/.style={
                                        xmin=-1,
                                        xmax=2,
                                        enlargelimits=true
                                 }
                             }]
\nextgroupplot
\addplot coordinates{(0,0)(1,1)(2,2)};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot coordinates{(0,2)(1,1)(2,0)};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot coordinates{(0,2)(1,1)(2,1)};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot coordinates{(0,2)(1,1)(1,0)};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This requires xmin and xmax to be specified.  Is it possible to achieve the same result automatically?

Comment: @mynoduesp Then we need to harvest all the `xmax` values from each plot and choose the largest one. I'll try to see if I can find something but I don't have much hope.